# How to order a vector using some predefined sequence in Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a predefined sequence of elements like this in a vector, the vector contains thousands of elements :

207.1   226.1   229.1   231.1   210.1    239.1   235.1   201.1   247.1  245.1   197.1    203.1   246.1   249.1   196.1   248.1   244.1    238.1

In a different vector I have the same elements as in the predefined vector but in a scattered way like this

226.1   225.1  205.1  220.1   220.1  237.1   226.1   212.1  212.1  205.1  205.1   202.1   202.1   192.1   192.1  191.1   191.1   192.1   192.1   192.1

Now I want to club up the elements in the scattered vector so that the order of the predefined vector is maintained, so the result should be like this

207.1  207.1   207.1   226.1   226.1   226.1   226.1  229.1   229.1  229.1  229.1 .  .  .
Is there any way to do this using CUDA thrust?

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a few assumptions that I think are necessary:

1. Your first "predefined" sequence has no duplicates.  If there were duplicates, and they were not adjacent, I cannot come up with an ordering strategy
2. Your second "scattered" sequence does not have any elements which are not also in the first sequence.  If there were, I would have no idea where to place these or how to order them

With those assumptions, here is one possible method, using the above definitions of "first" and "second" sequences:

1. For the first sequence, provide a vector of the same length (the "index" sequence) that indicates the index of the value:

   ```
    207.1 226.1 229.1 231.1 ...
        0     1     2     3 ...
   ```
2. Perform a `sort_by_key` to order the first sequence.  The index sequence will now be scrambled.
3. Using the ordered first sequence, use [`thrust::lower_bound`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__vectorized__binary__search_gab6283107548915e5541be0e3efe958f1.html#gab6283107548915e5541be0e3efe958f1) on the second sequence, to find which value of the first sequence it matches.
4. Using the matching value's index for each element in the second sequence (via `thrust::permutation_iterator`), `sort_by_key` the second sequence by matching value index.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t41.cu
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int max_samples_per_element = 4;
typedef float dt;
typedef int it;

int main(){
  // seq 1 and 2 data setup
  // host
  dt seq_1[] = {207.1, 226.1, 229.1, 231.1, 210.1, 239.1, 235.1, 201.1, 247.1, 245.1, 197.1, 203.1, 246.1, 249.1, 196.1, 248.1, 244.1, 238.1};
  it seq_1_sz = sizeof(seq_1)/sizeof(seq_1[0]);
  thrust::host_vector<dt> seq_2_hv;
  for (int i = seq_1_sz-1; i >= 0; i--){
    int element_samples = rand()%max_samples_per_element;
    element_samples++;
    for (int j = 0; j < element_samples; j++)
      seq_2_hv.push_back(seq_1[i]);
  }
  // device
  thrust::device_vector<dt> seq_2_dv = seq_2_hv;
  thrust::device_vector<dt> seq_1_dv(seq_1, seq_1+seq_1_sz);
  thrust::device_vector<it> index(seq_1_dv.size());
  thrust::device_vector<it> index2(seq_2_dv.size());
  thrust::sequence(index.begin(), index.end());
  //process data
  thrust::sort_by_key(seq_1_dv.begin(), seq_1_dv.end(), index.begin());
  thrust::lower_bound(seq_1_dv.begin(), seq_1_dv.end(), seq_2_dv.begin(), seq_2_dv.end(), index2.begin());
  auto my_pi = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(index.begin(), index2.begin());
  thrust::sort_by_key(my_pi, my_pi+index2.size(), seq_2_dv.begin());
  // display results
  thrust::host_vector<dt> result = seq_2_dv;
  thrust::copy_n(seq_1, seq_1_sz, std::ostream_iterator<dt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<dt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t41 t41.cu -O3 -lineinfo -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -std=c++14
$ ./t41
207.1,226.1,229.1,231.1,210.1,239.1,235.1,201.1,247.1,245.1,197.1,203.1,246.1,249.1,196.1,248.1,244.1,238.1,
207.1,207.1,207.1,226.1,229.1,229.1,229.1,231.1,231.1,231.1,231.1,210.1,210.1,210.1,210.1,239.1,239.1,239.1,235.1,235.1,235.1,235.1,201.1,201.1,201.1,247.1,247.1,245.1,245.1,197.1,203.1,203.1,203.1,246.1,246.1,246.1,246.1,249.1,249.1,196.1,196.1,196.1,196.1,248.1,248.1,244.1,244.1,244.1,238.1,238.1,238.1,238.1,
$
```

I'm not suggesting the above code is defect-free or suitable for any particular purpose.  My objective here is to demonstrate a possible method, not provide a fully tested code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer , I am facing compilation errors like :- "error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)" . "error: no suitable conversion function from "thrust::permutation_iterator<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>>" to "int" exists" .

Comment: in the declaration of auto my_pi = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(index.begin(), index2.begin());

Comment: use CUDA 11.1 and compile exactly as I have shown here.

Comment: Ok, it really helped. Thank you.